# What's wrong with this rewrite rule (redirect a directory request to another server)?

Tags: mod-rewrite

I'm try to redirect any request to mydomain.com/video/(.*) to video.mydomain.com/$1.
I have the following rule:

```
RewriteRule ^video/(.*)$  http://video.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Instead it follows an additional rewrite rule which I have later which redirects all requests to index.php.

Comment: Do you maybe have some RewriteCond command before that could affect it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a direct answer to the question, but there is a simpler way to do this without mod_rewrite:

```
Redirect permanent /video http://video.mydomain.com/
```

Comment: Still don't know the answer to my original question but, +1 For KISS!

Answer (score 1):

You forgot one slash after the start anchor:

```
RewriteRule ^/video/(.*)$  http://video.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Only if the rewrite rule is in httpd.conf. If it's in .htaccess the OP's rule shouldn't have that slash.

Comment: Can you give a bit more context, then? Otherwise it'll be too much guesswork. Where are the RewriteRules located in? Surrounded by what other conf?